# Autoconf: default out-of-the-box optimizations vs. cross-compilation

Tags: build-automation, autotools, autoconf

I am the lead developer of a software package for which performance is of utmost importance. The performance of said software can drastically improve when certain facilities are available, such as:

- software libraries (e.g. BLAS, LAPACK, ...)
- support for SSE, MMX, ...

I am in a situation where I find it difficult to decide on the most sensible approach. The way I see things, these are my options:

1. Ensuring portability and correct cross-compilation: by making use of available facilities optional and force users to explicitly enable them using -enable-X flags etc. This is necessary for portability because facilities available on the build platform may not be present on the target platform. PRO: portability and cross-compilation working properly. CON: novice users will forget optimizations and consequently suffer from performance loss.
2. Make life easy for the novice user: automatically check for availability of libraries and functions like SSE during the configure-phase and subsequently use all available facilities. PRO: user gets an optimized version of the software without fidgeting. CON: portability not guaranteed (ex. cross-compilation is broken when the host has SSE and the target does not. I don't expect my users to cross-compile, but death and taxes are the only certainty in life.).

I am currently leaning towards option 2 since this is what I expect most users to appreciate. Additionally, it may make more sense to cater to the novice in default behaviour.I am aware that this constitutes a cardinal sin in terms of portability. What do you guys think is the most sensible approach?

Are there any solutions to my predicament which I am unaware of?

Comment: Knowing the definition of novice would help.  Packages deployed to other developers who you'd expect to know such things is different from packages sent to the general public.  Ultimately I feel like this is a question without a factual answer, but if "novice" really means novice, I would tend to lean towards things working out of the box, guaranteed.  Anyone experienced enough to know something isn't optimized enough can figure that part out for himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not build the non-optimized binaries regardless of the availability of SSE libraries, and determine at run time which versions would be used?  If you use dynamic linking, this shouldn't result in any performance draw or overhead at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it led me to consider CPU dispatching using gcc's STT_GNU_IFUNC. This seems like an elegant solution with regards to automatic use of CPU capabilities such as SSE, AVX etc.

Answer (score 1):

This question is inherently subjective, but I think option (1) is a better choice - since you specify that "performance is of utmost importance."

Most users of a package (i.e., distro users) will be happy with either pre-built packages, or source builds with default options. If performance *is* critical, it is reasonable to expect the user to be familiar with compiler flags and `configure ...` usage. If a user is not bothered by performance, or is too lazy to read a simple `README` in the distribution, then the default build should just be something that works - it needn't be optimal.

I'm not sure about the disadvantages of cross-compilation - it seems you might have `host` and `target` confused, as `target` is rare outside of building cross-compiler tools. Correct use of the `host` triple in conjunction with `config.guess` gives a lot of useful information. For example:

```
case $host_cpu in
    x86_64) ... we always have SSE available ... ;;
esac
```

Now let's say you specify `-march=core2` as a [cross] compiler flag:

```
#if defined (__SSE3__)
#include <pmmintrin.h> /* (SSE3 Intel intrinsics)
#endif
```

would work even with a cross compiler. (Although `<immintrin.h>` is preferable nowadays)

In short, a novice user gets a novice build. You cannot optimize for every possible host and environment combination, but you can provide options.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Brett. I completely agree that users should be reading README's, but unfortunately this is often not the case. Novice users, in this particular case, refers to those that know little more than the standard configure-make-make install chain.

That said, I do agree with your point regarding the use of options. Additionally, I believe part of the problem (use of CPU capabilities such as SSE) can be solved through CPU dispatching (e.g. gcc's STT_GNU_IFUNC).